# How to save many-to-many related entities into context in ASP.NET Core from Angular framework?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

My models in ASP.NET Core are:

```
public class Customer
{
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }        
    public string CustomerName { get; set; } 
       
    public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }       
}

public class Invoice
{
    public long InvoiceId { get; set; }        
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }       
    public long InvoicePrice { get; set; } 
        
    // Foreign key   
    [Display(Name = "Customer")]  
    public virtual long CustomerId { get; set; }        
    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")] 
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        
    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceCommodity> InvoiceCommodities { get; set; }
}
    
public class Commodity
{
    public long CommodityId { get; set; }        
    public string CommodityName { get; set; }   
        
    public virtual ICollection<InvoiceCommodity> InvoiceCommodities { get; set; }
}
    
public class InvoiceCommodity
{
    public long InvoiceCommodityId { get; set;         
    public long Tonnage { get; set; }        
    public long SalesPrice { get; set; }
        
    public long InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }   
        
    public long CommodityId { get; set; }
    public virtual Commodity Commodity { get; set; }
}
    
public class InvoiceDto
{
    public long InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public DateTime InvoiceDate { get; set; }
    public long InvoicePrice { get; set; }   

    // Foreign key   
    [Display(Name = "Customer")]  
    public virtual long CustomerId { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<Models.InvoiceCommodity> InvoiceCommodities { get; set; }        
}
```

The same as in Angular:

```
export class Customer {
  public customerId?: number;
  public customerName?: string;  
  public invoices?: Invoice[];
}

export class Invoice {
  public invoiceId?: number; 
  public invoiceDate?: Date;
  public invoicePrice?: number;
  public customerId?: number;
  public invoiceCommodities?: InvoiceCommodity[];
}

export class Commodity {
  public commodityId?: number;
  public commodityName?: string;
  public invoiceCommodities?: InvoiceCommodity[];
}

export class InvoiceCommodity {
  public invoiceCommodityId?: number;
  public tonnage?: number;  
  public salesPrice?: number;
  public invoice?: Invoice;
  public commodity?: Commodity;
}
```

The `DbContext` class is:

```
public class RepositoryContext : DbContext
{
    public RepositoryContext(DbContextOptions<RepositoryContext> options)
            : base(options) { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating (ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
            modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceCommodity>().HasKey(ic => new
            {
                ic.CommodityId, ic.InvoiceId
            });
            modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceCommodity>()
                .HasOne(ic => ic.Invoice)
                .WithMany(i => i.InvoiceCommodities)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.InvoiceId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<InvoiceCommodity>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Commodity)
                .WithMany(ct => ct.InvoiceCommodities)
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.CommodityId);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
        
        public DbSet<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Commodity> Commodities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<InvoiceCommodity> InvoiceCommodities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

The `invoiceController` action method to add new invoice is this (it should be noted that these actions have been implemented for `InvoiceCommodity` and `Commodity` as well):

```
[HttpPost("addInvoice")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateInvoice([FromBody] InvoiceDto invoice)
{
    try
    {
        if (invoice is null)
        {
            return BadRequest("Invoice object is null");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest("Invalid model object");
        }

        var invoiceEntity = _mapper.Map<Invoice>(source:invoice);
        _repository.Invoice.CreatInvoice(invoiceEntity);
        await _repository.SaveAsync();

        var invoiceResult = _mapper.Map<InvoiceDto>(source:invoiceEntity);

        return Ok(invoiceResult);
    }
    catch
    {
        return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
    }
}
```

Getting the customer invoices by customerId action method is:

```
[HttpGet("customer/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomerById([FromRoute] long id)
{
    try
    {
        var customer = await _repository.Customer.GetCustomerByIdAsync(id);

        if (customer is null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var customerResult = _mapper.Map<CustomerDto>(source:customer);

        return Ok(customerResult);
    }
    catch
    {
        return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
    }
}
        
//===================== GetCustomerByIdAsync method ========
public async Task<Models.Customer> GetCustomerByIdAsync(long id)
{
    var customerFound = await FindByCondition(customer => customer.CustomerId.Equals(id))
                .Include(c => c.Invoices)
                .ThenInclude(invoice => invoice.InvoiceCommodities)
                .ThenInclude(commodity => commodity.Commodity)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    if (customerFound != null)
    {
        if (customerFound.Invoices != null)
        {
            foreach (var invoice in customerFound.Invoices)
            {
                invoice.Customer = null;

                if (invoice.InvoiceCommodities != null)
                {
                    foreach (var commodity in invoice.InvoiceCommodities)
                    {
                        commodity.Invoice.Customer = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }                
    }

    return  customerFound;
}
```

We already added the commodities through a client-side modal and they are gettable through Swagger as well as client-side action: from Swagger:

```
[
  {
    "commodityId": 1,
    "commodityName": "C1",
  },
  {
    "commodityId": 2,
    "commodityName": "C2",
  }
]
```

On the other hand, Customers are already added. so far, now when we add new invoice for a given customer in client-side as follows:

```
addNewInvoice(): boolean {
    if(this.invoiceDetails.length != 0) {
    
      this.newInvoice = new Invoice();
      
      this.newInvoice.customerId = this.customerSpecs.customerId;
      this.newInvoice.invoiceDate = this.invoiceDateValue;
      this.newInvoice.invoicePrice = this.invoicePrice;
      
      this.invoiceDetails.forEach( ids => {
      
        this.newCommodity = new Commodity();
        this.newInvoiceCommodity = new InvoiceCommodity();
        
        this.newCommodity.commodityId = ids.commodityId;
        this.newCommodity.commodityName = ids.commodityName;

        this.newInvoiceCommodity.salesPrice = ids.salesPrice;
        this.newInvoiceCommodity.tonnage = ids.tonnage;

        this.newInvoiceCommodity.invoice = this.newInvoice;
        this.newInvoiceCommodity.commodity = this.newCommodity;
        this.invoiceCommodityService.addInvoiceCommodity(this.newInvoiceCommodity);
        
        this.newInvoice.invoiceCommodities?.push(this.newInvoiceCommodity);
      });
      
      this.invoicesService.addNewInvoice(this.newInvoice).subscribe( ct => {
      // adding newInvoice is successfully 
        console.log(`added invoice id: ${ct.invoiceId}`); // 1
        console.log(`added invoice customer Id: ${ct.customerId}`); // 3
        console.log(`added invoice Date: ${ct.invoiceDate}`); // 2022 ...
        console.log(`added invoice price: ${ct.invoicePrice}`); // 1000$   
      });
    }
    return false
  }
```

The new Invoice is added successfully, but when we try to get invoice details of the customer, we see these data fetched by swagger, because in client-side show us no details for the invoice! even, when I try to get Invoice by id from Swagger, I faced error 500 (server error). also, to get invoiceCommodities themselves, Swagger gives me empty collection ([]).

```
{
    "customerId": 3,
    "customerName": "Mr X",
    "invoices": [
      {
        "invoiceId": 1,
        "invoiceDate": "2022-12-18T06:56:37.642",
        "invoicePrice": 1000,
        "invoiceCommodities": [],
        "customerId": 3,
        "customer": null
      }
    ],
  },
  // other customers list ...
```

As you can see in addnewInvoice method, we Post each of the invoiceCommodity and then push them in the invoiceCommodities property of newInvoice and Post it at the end.

What action or async method should I write on the backend or frontend so that an Invoice create correctly for given customer and its details can be viewed on the frontend?

This issue has become a big problem for me and I did a lot of research, but unfortunately I did not find a suitable solution. Please provide a suitable solution for this problem.

Comment: There's a lot of code there but I can tell you one thing for certain: your exception handling in `GetCustomerById` is terrible. You shouldn't have a `try.. catch` there at all, and you further compound the problem by generating your own 500 error but removing all details from it, even for debugging. Also, a catch all exception handler is considered bad code in .NET for a reason. There's a lot of other things that I'm wrong with the code from a design perspective but it's too much to go into now, suffice it to say you're writing way too much code especially in the client side.

Comment: On the client side, a method has been written to take the data from the user and post it to the backend in the form of a model. On the backend side, an action has been written to save and retrieve data. That's not a lot of coding in my opinion. The rest of the cases are the models defined on both sides!.

Comment: The reason why I brought all the items, including models and methods, is that all angles of the problem are completely clear and a suitable solution is provided.

Comment: On the client side, JS/TS, using classes as serialized and deserialized DTOs is just horrible design, a source of bugs, and requires needless code. I'm not going to argue the point further because it will be off topic. Anyway, keep it simple and learn JavaScript so that you can write effective typescript.